# detection of symbol from vehicle plate in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am doing project on detecting number and symbol(person with disability) from vehicle number plate in MATLAB. I have created templates for the same.while retrieving the number from plate, got miscellaneous results. My main concern is to  read properly the number and sign from plate. Can anyone help me on this?.[image]

% Program for templates

```
desiredsize = [42 24];
files = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '0', 'sign'};
NewTemplates1 = cell(size(files));
for fileidx = 1:numel(files)
   img = imread([files{fileidx}, '.png']);
   img= rgb2gray(img);
   img = imresize(img, desiredsize);
   NewTemplates1{fileidx} = img;
end
```

% program for number extraction

```
clc;
clear all;
load NewTemplates1;
word=[ ];
img=imread('2222.jpg');
figure,imshow(img);
[~,cc]=size(img);
picture=imresize(img,[300 500]);

if size(picture,3)==3
  picture=rgb2gray(picture);  %grey values are btwn 0 to 1 or 0 to 255
end



threshold = graythresh(picture);  %greythresh gives the threshold value of greyscale image
picture =~im2bw(picture,threshold);   %black nd white values are 0 or 1 and values greater thn threshold=1,rest=0 and invert white and black ie 1 to 0 and 0 to 1
picture = bwareaopen(picture,30);  % those things that have less than 30 pixels are removed


if cc>2000
    picture1=bwareaopen(picture,3500);  %those things that have less than 3500 pixels are removed ie excluding nmbr plate
else
picture1=bwareaopen(picture,3000);  %those things that have less than 3000 pixels are removed ie excluding nmbr plate
end
figure,imshow(picture1);
picture2=picture-picture1;  %only number plate is left
picture2=bwareaopen(picture2,50);   %only text is there in the nmbr plate
figure,imshow(picture2);
title('plate extracted');
[L,Ne]=bwlabel(picture2,8);
%% Measure properties of image regions
propied=regionprops(L,'BoundingBox');
hold on
%% Plot Bounding Box
for n=1:size(propied,1)
  rectangle('Position',propied(n).BoundingBox,'EdgeColor','g','LineWidth',2)
end
hold off
pause (1)
% Compute the number of letters in template file
num_letras=size(NewTemplates1,2);
%% Objects extraction
figure
for n=1:Ne
  [r,c] = find(L==n);
  n1=picture2(min(r):max(r),min(c):max(c));
  img_r=imresize(n1,[42 24]);
  letter=readLetter1(img_r);
        % Letter concatenation
  word=[word letter];
  fid = fopen('noPlate.txt', 'wt'); % This portion of code writes the number plate
    fprintf(fid,'%s\n',word);      % to the text file, if executed a notepad file with the
    fclose(fid);                      % name noPlate.txt will be open with the number plate written.
    winopen('noPlate.txt')

%   imshow(~n1);
  pause(0.5);
end
```

Comment: What are you having a difficulty with? Please be specific. See also: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/).

Comment: @Dev-iL. My code is not able to extract the number from plate correctly. It is showing erroneous result and also symbol is not detected,showing 'sign' word as output while image is expected to be.

Comment: This is still too broad. My suggestion: find an example where your code is not working and edit your question to include only it and the code that you think is causing the issue.

Comment: Did I get this right? You're trying to perform Unicode OCR, but it outputs the wrong characters. You expect it to output "قطر‎ ♿ 012345" but it gives you something else? Does it work for some input images and fails for others? Did you think about neural nets?

Comment: @Dev-iL. Yeah Right. I need to extract this (''‎ ♿ 012345'') from number plate.